# How to tell user's locale units settings

Tags: ios, swiftui, locale, units-of-measurement

I'm in the process of internationalizing my iOS app to handle both US customary units (imperial) and SI (metric). Is there a way to tell what the user's preferred settings are based on their locale or other settings info?

I ask the user to input `Measurement()` data and need to know what unit to assign it when calling `let weight = Measurement(value: 75, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)`. I would like to be able to assign the correct unit for the user without needing to ask them for their preference. I know that the system can handle the correct output units using `weight.formatted()`. But what about input?

My app is very user data input oriented using the following `UnitType`s:

```
Measurement      Imperial            Metric

Length           feet                meters
Distance         miles               kilometers
Mass             pounds              kilograms
Displacement     cubicInches         liters
Volume           gallons             liters
Power            horsepower          kilowatts
Temperature      farenheit           celcius
AtmosPressure    inchesOfMercury     millibars
Speed            milesPerHour        kilometersPerHour
```

Comment: OK, so I can run a test for each `UnitType`, and save that result. I was thinking Apple would have provided an easy way to fetch the user's prefs, or be able to apply them behind the scenes in the same way they do for output.

Comment: Too bad this was closed as a duplicate, anyway short story is that you can handle the input just as easy and let the system handle the locale.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, can you expand on that thought? How do I handle the input "just as easy". This is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proper initializer for each unit like:

```
let currentMassUnit = UnitMass(forLocale: .current)
```

<sub>Note that maybe the user not prefers their locale for the calculations.</sub>